# Can acing the upper level course compensate background of no basic course in graduate application

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics

I am an international master student in Germany who wants to apply graduate schools in US or Canada. I have an unconventional background, I want to study mathematics but I don't have courses of basic analysis and abstract algebra. Due to language problem, I can't take the course in my university. Now if I get good grades in upper lever (graduate) mathematics courses, can it compensate that I don't have basic courses?
Would it be a big disadvantage in Phd application?

Comment: Are you planning to take the mathematics subject GRE?

Comment: Do you satisfy the entry requirements of the graduate schools to which you want to apply?

Comment: @mmeent Yes, this is required for most school

Comment: @user2768 Some of them do not state explicitly the background requirement,some of them said it is not ideal.

Comment: @Ken.Wong Doesn't that give you an answer?

Comment: @user2768 So you mean some school rejected me already, but does this hold for other school,which I (seem to) satisfy their entry requirement?

Comment: @Ken.Wong No. As you've said: _Some [schools] said it is not ideal [to not have courses of basic analysis and abstract algebra]._ You have your answer: It isn't ideal.

Comment: Only indirectly relevant, but in the context of of _undergraduate_ admissions, I've noticed that the assessed learning outcomes of A-level (UK qualification typically taken at age 18) mathematics do _not_ encompass the assessed learning outcomes of GCSE (UK qualification typically taken at age 16) mathematics; so it's not always safe to assume that a candidate with good grades in an advanced qualification has grasped the learning outcomes of a more basic qualification in the same subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would look slightly odd, but good grades in advanced courses would generally be seen as sufficient to show that you understand the material. In the end, graduate admission committees aren't so much interested in knowing *how* you acquired necessary background knowledge than knowing *that you have it*. How that is demonstrated is secondary, and acing upper level courses is certainly one acceptable way to do so.